# OTP Owncloud label hide

Tags: javascript, label, owncloud, one-time-password

I use the One Time Password App for Owncloud, witch adds an second password field on the logon form witch authenticates against the multi otp service.

The Probleme is that the label of the textfield from the otp input field does not get hidden.

The following .js is relevant:

```
(function() {
    var saml = document.createElement('script'); saml.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(saml); })();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$('#password').parent().hide();
        $('#password').parent().removeClass("infield groupbottom");
        $('#password').parent().addClass("infield groupmiddle");
        $('#password').parent().after(
            '<p class="infield groupbottom">'+
            '<input id="otpPassword" type="password" placeholder="" data-
typetoggle="#show" value="" name="otpPassword"'+
'original-title="">'+ '<input type="text" name="password-clone"
tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;"
original-title="">'+ '<label class="infield" for="otpPassword">One
Time Password</label>'+ '<img id="password-icon" class="svg" alt=""
src="/core/img/actions/password.svg">'+

'</p>');
        $('#remember_login').hide();
        $('#remember_login+label').hide();
        //$('#submit').hide();
});
```

Or see here: http://pastebin.com/8YX2FEGt

Maybe someone got a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I do figured out to fix the courser problem

You can fix this issue with:

```
>> core/css/styles.css

Line: 550 // width wert change
#body-login input[type="text"],
#body-login input[type="password"] {
    width: 11.7em;
}


Line: 372 // add padding
#body-login .groupbottom input {
    margin-top: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    padding-left:35px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset !important;
}
```